# Bluetooth events not triggered by manifest BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I've an app (target sdk: 29) which listens to events whenever a bluetooth device is connected. If I register the receiver sy runtime with code then it works fine. But with the manifest it doesn't.

The receiver in the manifest looks like the following (i tried several actions);

```
<receiver android:name=".Services.BluetoothService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BluetoothService extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("Smartdoor", "Device connected");
            NotificationBuilder.show(context, "SmartDoor", "Device connected");
        }   else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("Smartdoor", "Device disconnected");
            NotificationBuilder.show(context, "SmartDoor", "Device disconnected");
        }
    }
}
        </receiver>
```

API version 26 has added some limitations to implicit broadcastlisteners but excluded the ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED event. So I should be able to listen to events in the background. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: Do you have Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH added in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yes I have added several bluetooth permissions.